# Number of iterations for Gauss-Seidel

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am having some difficulty understanding the following solved problem:

[image]

**Question:**

Shouldn't we have $||T||^k_{\infty} ||e^{0}||_{\infty} \leq 10^{-6}$ instead?

Where does the $5$ come from? And why $5 \times 10^{−7}$ and not $10^{−6}$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have to limit the *radius* of the error interval. To get a diameter of the error interval of $10^{-6}$ or less, you need to keep the radius of the error interval at or below $0.5·10^{-6}=5·10^{-7}$.

To get one decimal place under normal rounding rules, you can not use an error bound of $0.1$, since for an exact value of $0.3$ and a measured/approximated value of $0.37$ or $0.22$ both would fall  into this error bound but would be rounded to $0.4$ and $0.2$ respectively.